# PHP: How can create again the header when another page is created?

Tags: php, twig, dompdf

I have a twig file, and I am using dompdf to generate a file about members of a company and information about them. the thing is that, if there are too many members, more than one page are created and the header gets created only in the first page.

The information for all members are created using a for `for` loop.

How can I tell the `for` loop to check if there is another page to create as many headers as pages?

This is how it is now:

[image: this is the pages as they are now]

And this is how I need it:

[image: And this is how I want it]

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code you are having problems with?

Comment: Hi Dave, I already put the code :)

Comment: You need to reduce that to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's far too much there for someone to try and go through.